# Firefox 4 (b7) per-tab profiles

Tags: firefox

I use multiple email accounts from one provider via their webmail interface, which like most uses cookies for session management.

What I'd like to do is be able to use both at once, by isolating the tab's cookies from each other.

I tried using the IE-Tab extension, which acheives this seperation by embedding the other application's viewport while keeping it's runtime environment seperate.

But Internet Explorer doesn't use a master password, or implement any sort of password security for that matter- so it's not an option.

The best I can come up with is to open 2 seperate Firefox windows, each using different profiles, but then I couldn't just change tabs to move between accounts.

Does anyone know how to implement a solution to this?

Preferably to work with Firefox 4 beta 7, which is what I'm running at the moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer contains only very partial solutions, I'm afraid.)

The well-established [CookieSwap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3255/) allows you to quickly switch between personas. That's not nearly as convenient as per-tab or per-window cookies, which the author of CookieSwap claims “poses some significant challenges”.

There's a fairly young extension called [Account Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/78912/). I have no idea whether it would work or how smoothly.

For Google Chrome, [Cookie Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lbgngibmlgcicanoijcnijbkmjpkifkb?hl=en) and [Swap My Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dffhipnliikkblkhpjapbecpmoilcama?hl=en) are similar to Firefox's CookieSwap. Out of the box, Google Chrome has two sets of cookies: one for normal windows and one for incognito (“private browsing”) windows. I don't know whether you can get more.

If the email provider is Google, a solution is to use their [multiple sign-in](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=28776) feature.

Comment: I saw cookie switcher, but not account switcher. For now these won't work with FF4b7. Cookieswitcher has similar functionality as the 2 windows with different profiles, just without a whole new window running. If they could container-ize 1 tab not all it'd be ideal. It wasn't clear how the other one was different, and I couldn't install it to this version to see. Also my provider isn't Google, so that's not an available function to make use of either. Thanks nonetheless.